# Check each gunicorn worker?

Tags: gunicorn

I want to ensure on startup that each gunicorn worker (which happens to be a Django app) is healthy and started.  If I submit an HTTP request to check, gunicorn will route it to a worker, but I want to check them all.

(Note: each worker takes ~30 seconds to start up, because it has some work to do.  I know this is non-traditional, but it's the best solution at the moment, believe me.)

Any way to do this?